# node_modules/cheerio/lib/types.d.ts:2:48 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uppercase'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was trying to build a project after cloning the repo.On project compilation it gives following errors

node_modules/cheerio/lib/types.d.ts:2:48 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uppercase'.

2 declare type AlphaNumeric = LowercaseLetters | Uppercase | `${number}`;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/cheerio/lib/types.d.ts:2:78 - error TS1110: Type expected.

2 declare type AlphaNumeric = LowercaseLetters | Uppercase | `${number}`;
~~~

Following is the package.json

```js
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build && npm run copy:dir",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "npm run copy:dir && nest start",
    "start-development": "NODE_ENV=development nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/src/main.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run prebuild",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "copy:dir": "mkdir -p dist/config/ && mkdir -p dist/formats/ && cp -R src/config/* dist/config/ && cp -R src/formats/* dist/formats/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.67.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.67.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-textract": "^3.58.0",
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.5.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.1.4",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.8.0",
    "@trycourier/courier": "^1.7.1",
    "airtable": "^0.10.0",
    "api": "^3.4.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.824.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "buffer-alloc": "^1.2.0",
    "buffer-alloc-unsafe": "^1.1.0",
    "buffer-xor": "^2.0.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "cpx": "^1.2.1",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "eb": "0.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.2.0",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "express-openid-connect": "^2.0.0",
    "express-xml-bodyparser": "^0.3.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
    "mongoose-audit-trail": "^2.0.7",
    "mongoose-diff-history": "^2.1.0",
    "nest-winston": "^1.4.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "order-id": "^2.1.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "stripe": "^8.126.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-cloudwatch": "^2.5.2",
    "xml2json": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.6",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.10",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.9.1",
    "cucumber": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
    "eslint": "7.7.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.4.2",
    "jest-cucumber": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is your package: make sure you're using the correct version of cheerio and its types for the code you've written. If it isn't: file an issue with the person whose repo you're trying to use first.